# Xamarin Forms which component to choose

Tags: forms, xamarin, layout, components

I build an App with Xamarin Forms for Android and iOS and am looking for a layout which can contain a dynamic amount of children. It also should work with ItemTemplate. I want to add multiple views which have differeng width. If the width is too large, to be right to the previous sibling, it should break to the next line. Like in the picture. Do you know a Component which does that? Ty!

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout

Answer (score 0):

[FlexLayout](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/adaptive-mobile-designs-with-flexlayout/) flows and can have a template or binding like any other Forms layout.